# Notepad++ - is there a way to control the word separators

Tags: configuration, notepad++, config

In Notepad++ (beloved) I could not helped but notice that the `ctrl+left` (`SCI_WORDRIGHT`) would jump on the next - signs.

Example:
**WORD-ID-1** (is actually 3 words, WORD, ID , 1) vs. **WORD_ID_1** is one word.

I am looking for setting to control that behavior.

Is there a way to define the white space what would control the `SCI_WORDRIGHT/LEFT behavior?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from Damien Plumettaz on question "notepad++ select hyphenated text" totally works for me.